# How to link a domain in multitenent to a domain without multitenant in Grails?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, multi-tenant

Environment:

- Grails 5.3.2

I build a web with multitenent SCHEMA.

Now I have two domains. One is with tenant and the other is not.

Tuser (with tenant):

```
package com.workerorder.domain.tenant

import com.workerorder.domain.Vehicle
import grails.gorm.MultiTenant


class Tuser implements MultiTenant<Tuser> {
    String userid
  
    static hasMany = [vehicles: Vehicle]
    static constraints = {
        userid          maxSize: 20, unique: true, index:'tu_userid'
    }
}
```

Vehicle (without tenant) is shared by all tenants, so it is in public. therefore it doesn't need to be in tenent.

```
package com.workerorder.domain

import com.workerorder.constant.FieldLen

class Vehicle {
    String brandName
    String modelName
    String spec
    static constraints = {
        brandName       maxSize: FieldLen.BRAND_NAME_LEN
        modelName       maxSize: FieldLen.VEHICLE_MODEL_LEN
        spec            maxSize: FieldLen.VEHICLE_SPEC_LEN, nullable: true
    }
}
```

When I start the web, it appears below error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsInterceptorMappedInterceptor': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#14e62633' of type [org.grails.plugins.web.interceptors.GrailsInterceptorHandlerInterceptorAdapter] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#14e62633': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'serviceRegistry'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastore': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: An association from the table tuser_vehicle refers to an unmapped class: com.workerorder.domain.Vehicle
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
...
...

    at worker.order.Application.main(Application.groovy:11)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsInterceptorMappedInterceptor': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#14e62633' of type [org.grails.plugins.web.interceptors.GrailsInterceptorHandlerInterceptorAdapter] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#14e62633': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'serviceRegistry'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastore': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: An association from the table tuser_vehicle refers to an unmapped class: com.workerorder.domain.Vehicle
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:389)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:134)
...
...

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: An association from the table tuser_vehicle refers to an unmapped class: com.workerorder.domain.Vehicle
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:224)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:117)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:311)
    ... 68 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: An association from the table tuser_vehicle refers to an unmapped class: com.workerorder.domain.Vehicle
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.secondPassCompileForeignKeys(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1801)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.secondPassCompileForeignKeys(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1772)
```

Any suggestion?